# using scrapy, how to get value from inside a tag

Tags: xml, xpath, scrapy

from the following source code:

```html
<div class="units">
    <select class="select tierprices" onchange="somethting.changeUnitPrice(this)">
        <option value="1" data-qtyid="qty-34"
                data-formated="&lt;span class=&quot;price&quot;&gt;AUD $867.64&lt;/span&gt;">
            Unit Price
        </option>
        <option value="5" data-qtyid="qty-34"
                data-formated="&lt;span class=&quot;price&quot;&gt;AUD $866.84&lt;/span&gt;">
            5+ ITEMS
        </option>
        <option value="10" data-qtyid="qty-34"
                data-formated="&lt;span class=&quot;price&quot;&gt;AUD $865.84&lt;/span&gt;">
            10+ ITEMS
        </option>
        <option value="50" data-qtyid="qty-34"
                data-formated="&lt;span class=&quot;price&quot;&gt;AUD $864.14&lt;/span&gt;">
            50+ ITEMS
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Using Scrapy, how do i get the value **AUD $867.64**

Comment: You have to show some effort, please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to get that price you have mentioned you can do it by xpath selector like this.

```py
response.xpath('//select//option[@value="1"]/@data-formated').re(r'&lt;span class=&quot;price&quot;&gt;(.*)&lt;/span&gt;')
```

Otherwise you can play around with xpath to get all prices. The output would be a list object.